SetActive only working for one object when I am calling it from another script
I am trying to have three separate buttons activate at the same time when call from another script but only the first button is activating despite all buttons using the same script.
the script inside of the buttons is currently,
public GameObject abilityButton;

public static AbilityManager main;

private void Awake()
{
   main = this;
   abilityButton.SetActive(false);
}

public void SelectAbility
{
   abilityButton.SetActive(true);
}

and in the other script to call the code,
AbilityManager.main.SelectAbility();

the script works in setting all of the buttons to inactive when called from awake but not when called from the other script. Any help is appreciated!

well your "abilityButton" variable can only hold reference to 1 button.. and so, if you make more, then it will likely only be the last one made....

The reason this is happening is because, as BugFinder said, AbilityManager only stores a reference to one of the buttons, rather a list of all the buttons. To help understand your problem, let me create a simpler view of what your problem looks like, in order to demonstrate the flow of execution:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    Button button1 = new Button();
    Button button2 = new Button();
    Button button3 = new Button();

    Button buttonToPress;

    buttonToPress = button1;
    buttonToPress = button2;
    buttonToPress = button3;

    buttonToPress.PressButton();

    Console.WriteLine($"Has pressed button1 : {button1}"); // false
    Console.WriteLine($"Has pressed button2 : {button2}"); // false
    Console.WriteLine($"Has pressed button3 : {button3}"); // true
}

class Button
{
    private bool isPressed = false;
    public void PressButton() => isPressed = !isPressed;
}

As you can see, the reason the code isn't working is because, even though we set buttonToPress equal to every button, it's only saved as the last value it was set to, which is why only 1 of the 3 buttons is pressed (in this case button3).
The solution is to change our variable from holding a single value to holding multiple values, by using either an array or, in this example, a list.
To do so we change the type of buttonToPress from storing a single Button, to instead a List<Button>, and by adding all the buttons we want to press to our list, buttonsToPress.Add(button). Finally, we use a loop, either a for or foreach, to press every button in our our list.
Here's what the code example looks like with all these changes in mind:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    Button button1 = new Button();
    Button button2 = new Button();
    Button button3 = new Button();

    List<Button> buttonsToPress = new List<Button>();

    buttonsToPress.Add(button1);
    buttonsToPress.Add(button2);
    buttonsToPress.Add(button3);

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonsToPress.Count; i++)
    {
        buttonsToPress[i].PressButton();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Has pressed button1 : {button1}"); // true
    Console.WriteLine($"Has pressed button2 : {button2}"); // true
    Console.WriteLine($"Has pressed button3 : {button3}"); // true
}

class Button
{
    private bool isPressed = false;
    public void PressButton() => isPressed = !isPressed;
}

I hope this helps to clear up why your code isn't working as expected, and you're able to come up with a solution using the provided information. Let me know if you have any questions, or if you need help applying it to your specific problem and I'd be happy to help!
